How to draw lines between the points of pose detection in flutter?
I have issues with data type when trying to give colors to draw lines between the detected body parts by posedetection!
I want the code to draw lines between the detected parts of the body without facing a problem with the color type. I think the problem accuors when i try to use color from image library in flutter and i don't know how to solve it.
I have tried multible things, but one and last one was the following:
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;
import 'package:google_mlkit_pose_detection/google_mlkit_pose_detection.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class PoseDetection {
  static final PoseDetector _poseDetector = PoseDetector(
    options: PoseDetectorOptions(
      mode: PoseDetectionMode.single,
    ),
  );

  static Future<void> detectPoses(String videoPath) async {
    final outputDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final directory = Directory(outputDirectory.path);
    List<File> frameFiles = directory.listSync()
        .where((entity) => entity is File && entity.path.endsWith('.jpg') && entity.path.contains('frame'))
        .map((entity) => entity as File)
        .toList();

    for (File frameFile in frameFiles) {
      final inputImage = InputImage.fromFile(frameFile);
      final List<Pose> poses = await _poseDetector.processImage(inputImage);

      img.Image? originalImage = img.decodeImage(frameFile.readAsBytesSync());

      for (final pose in poses) {
        var landmarks = pose.landmarks;

        // Create a list of points representing the body parts
        final List<Point<int>> bodyPoints = [
          for (var landmark in landmarks.values)
            Point(landmark.x.toInt(), landmark.y.toInt())
        ];

        // Draw lines connecting the body parts
        drawPolyline(originalImage!, bodyPoints, Colors.blue);
      }

      // Save the modified image back to disk
      File('${frameFile.path}_pose.jpg').writeAsBytesSync(img.encodeJpg(originalImage!));
    }
  }

  static void drawPolyline(img.Image image, List<Point<int>> points, Color color) {
    final List<Point<int>> pointsClosed = List.from(points)..add(points.first);
    for (int i = 0; i < pointsClosed.length - 1; i++) {
      final Point<int> currentPoint = pointsClosed[i];
      final Point<int> nextPoint = pointsClosed[i + 1];
      _drawLine(image, currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y, nextPoint.x, nextPoint.y, color);
    }
  }

  static void _drawLine(img.Image image, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, Color color) {
    while (true) {
      image.setPixel(x1, y1, color);
      if (x1 == x2 && y1 == y2) break;
      final int dx = (x2 - x1).abs(), sx = x1 < x2 ? 1 : -1;
      final int dy = -(y2 - y1).abs(), sy = y1 < y2 ? 1 : -1;
      int err = dx + dy, e2; /* error value e_xy */

      e2 = 2 * err;
      if (e2 >= dy) {
        err += dy;
        x1 += sx;
      } /* e_xy+e_x > 0 */
      if (e2 <= dx) {
        err += dx;
        y1 += sy;
      } /* e_xy+e_y < 0 */
    }
  }







  static void dispose() {
    _poseDetector.close();
  }
}


